# Data Binding and Lambda in Android

Tags: android

I'm learning how to use databinding.

My question is in line 2 [image: picture]

```
@{(*cb, isChecked*) ->    presenter.completeChanged(task, isChecked)}
```

How do I know the first parameter is checkbox `cb` and the second is boolean `isChecked`?

Are there any documents I can check out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do i know the first parameter is checkbox(cb) and the second is
>   boolean(isChecked)? are there any documents i can check out? thanks in
>   advance

you should always check the documentation. `onCheckChanged` is defined in the interface [CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html), and as you can notice from the documentation, the first argument is the CompoundButton (your CheckBox) and the second is a boolean

```
onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
```